# how to select name array of multiple select box using jquery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, loops

I just want the values selected of the question[],operator[], of the multiple select box using jquery,  Can anyone suggest me to get me out of here to get the values of question[] selected. Here is the html code,

```
<div class="conditions-container js-widget-container" style="">


                <div class="skip-logic-form-branch-statement ifStatement editing">



        <span class="skip-logic-form-branch-control">

            <span class="if-text" style="  display:block; ">IF</span>

            <select name="operator[]" class="form-control logic-operator" style="   display:none; ">
                <option value="and">AND</option>
                <option value="or">OR</option>
            </select>
        </span>


        <span class="selectContainer">
            <select name="question[]" class="form-control logic-question bound" onchange="getAnswer('a')">
                                <option value="752">Q1:que2</option>

                                <option value="745">Q2:a1</option>

                            </select>
            :

            <select name="answer[]" class="form-control logic-answer"><option value="-1">-- Select Answer Option --</option>

            <option value="2016">a4</option>
            <option value="2015">a3</option>
            <option value="2014">a2</option>
            <option value="2013">a1</option>

        </select>

            <select name="condition[]" class="form-control logic-condition">
                <option value="true">is selected</option>
                <option value="false">is not selected</option>
            </select>
                                            <span style="cursor: pointer" class="pull-right"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i> </span>

        </span>

    </div>


                <div class="skip-logic-form-branch-statement ifStatement editing">



        <span class="skip-logic-form-branch-control">

            <span class="if-text" style="   display:none; ">IF</span>

            <select name="operator[]" class="form-control logic-operator" style="  display:block; ">
                <option value="and">AND</option>
                <option value="or">OR</option>
            </select>
        </span>


        <span class="selectContainer">
            <select name="question[]" class="form-control logic-question bound" onchange="getAnswer('a')">
                                <option value="752">Q1:que2</option>

                                <option value="745">Q2:a1</option>

                            </select>
            :

            <select name="answer[]" class="form-control logic-answer"><option value="-1">-- Select Answer Option --</option>

            <option value="2016">a4</option>
            <option value="2015">a3</option>
            <option value="2014">a2</option>
            <option value="2013">a1</option>

        </select>

            <select name="condition[]" class="form-control logic-condition">
                <option value="true">is selected</option>
                <option value="false">is not selected</option>
            </select>
                                            <span style="cursor: pointer" class="pull-right"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i> </span>

        </span>

    </div>

                                        </div>
```

Jquery code

```
$("select[name='question[]']").map(function(){ alert($(this).val());

    });
```

Image

[image]

Comment: it's a select, just add an id and use $("#question").val();  Those don't look like multi selects, they're plain selects. A multi select would have the name attribute multiple

Comment: how can i give id to the question which is dynamically coming means while  clicking add a contition to this branch a new row will be created

Comment: there are many select box with the same name as clicking on add a condition to this branch, Id would be unique for one particular select, Please suggest some suitable ways